# Creating Variable or Object with Names from text file c++

Tags: c++, file, text

I'm wondering if you can set or create a Variable or Objects name from text file.

example: text file("Iron Copper Steel")

read the file and create a new Variable or Object with the name "Iron" then continue reading and create a new object or variable named "Copper", etc.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/28821/.

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot.

Object names/variable names are fixed before compiling the code.

You want to use an interpreted language

Answer (score 1):

A variable is a data item, which needs to be stored in memory, and the *name* is mapped to that memory location. Each variable name must be given at compile time (except the temporaries, which have no name). If you want to give anything a name which you will use for some reason, you can create a class which can have a `string` for name and you can set it after reading the file. But this is **totally different than the concept of *variable name* in C++**.